# Rstudio knit to PDF

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

The new version of Rstudio (0.98.932) has many new options including knit to PDF. An article describing the new version has a [comment from Dave](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/06/18/r-markdown-v2/#comment-10850) that says:

> ...after installing rstudio 0.98.932 I don’t get the little dropdown menu
>   for knit-pdf or word when editing a .Rmd file.

I'm having the same issue. A helpful response was posted:

> It might be that either:
>
> a) You are not running R 3.0 (which is required for RMarkdown v2); or
>
> b) You have a custom markdown renderer defined (markdownToHTML
>   option). You can check for this by executing:
>
> getOption(“rstudio.markdownToHTML”)

That solved Dave's problem (b), but when I run that command I get NULL

```
> getOption("rstudio.markdownToHTML")
NULL
```

Which I assume means I don't have a custom markdown renderer defined. (Previously I did in a cusomized `.Rprofile`, but I removed that.) My R version is 3.1.0.

Am I misunderstanding the `getOption` command? Could something else be tripping up my Rstudio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have just installed the new version of RStudio (0.98.932), which prompted me to upgrade a couple of packages (I can't remember which, although I see I have knitr 1.6, markdown 0.7 and rmarkdown 0.2.46). At first I had the same problem; there was only a single 'knit' option on the tool bar. I managed to get the ability to knit to .pdf by adding the following to the head of my .Rmd file.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Having done that, I now find I do have a drop down menu with options to knit to HTML, PDF and word. There's also a little gear icon that provides access to the R Markdown document options that wasn't there before. I have no idea what the problem was but it seems OK now!

Comment: you're a star! I think it was the updating of the packages that did it because now opening a new R markdown document brings up a dialogue box and it all works from there. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is still helpful as of Oct. 2018. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @nicholas response
This is also why I create new .Rmd documents through the RStudio gui

File > New File > R markdown.

This way the YAML header is populated correctly.