# RStudio knit button is not showing options

Tags: r, rstudio

I have run into issues with my Knit button in RStudio.

[image]

It is missing all the options of Knit to HTML, Knit to PDF etc.

I used to have these options. Even after restarting my Mac a few times, I don't have them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the suggestions here which appears to be the same question/problem:

[Rstudio knit to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308562/rstudio-knit-to-pdf/24309326#24309326)

Describes a few different issues resulting in the behaviour you have seen and solutions to these.

The main suggestions are:

a) You are not running R 3.0 (which is required for RMarkdown v2); or

b) You have a custom markdown renderer defined (markdownToHTML option). You can check for this by executing:

```
getOption(“rstudio.markdownToHTML”)
```

Some users have found that the following action also fixes the issue:
Add the following code to the head of an .Rmd file.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: pdf_document
---
```

That appeared to solve the problem.
Hopefully one of these solutions works for you.

Comment: I tried all the methods but none of them works for me. I found that I could use rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd","html_document") to knit it.