# RStudio knit button is not showing options - continued

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

The question has been already asked (and answered) in 2017
[RStudio knit button is not showing options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813072/rstudio-knit-button-is-not-showing-options)
and in 2014
[Rstudio knit to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308562/rstudio-knit-to-pdf/24309326#24309326).

Three cases are considered:

> a) You are not running R 3.0 (which is required for RMarkdown v2);
>   b) You have a custom markdown renderer
>
> ```
> getOption(“rstudio.markdownToHTML”)
> ```
>
> c) output: pdf_document  in YAML header

- Option c) has worked time ago but it has no effect now.
- Option a) I am using "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)" >> version 3.0
- Option b)

```
    > getOption("rstudio.markdownToHTML")
    function (inputFile, outputFile) 
    {
        system(paste("pandoc", shQuote(inputFile), "-o", shQuote(outputFile)))
    }
    
    > getOption("rstudio.markdownToPDF")
    NULL
```

"toHTML" is set (not by me, anyway it looks ok)
"toPDF"  does not exist

I tried erasing all I could concerning R and Rstudio and re-installing everything. No change: the options sub-button beside 'knit' button does not re-appear.

Comment: What is the extension of your currently opened file?

Comment: I work with "*.Rmd" files and "R Markdown" is visible in the box on the right of the lower border of the Source sub-window.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your R Studio session to see the lack of the Knit button?

Comment: Yes, this is a screenshot

Comment: (Oops, it took too long to complete!) Yes, [this is a screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19UgWBh-RuTF_0N41VWKCfOzIDhbrLgwh/view?usp=sharing)
I have no triangle on the right of the button.

Comment: Do you encounter this behaviour when using the default R Markdown template?

Comment: yes, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNrftQhaWhbOqsVAyJTp06_L9FfhZpTV/view?usp=sharing) is a screenshot of an Rmd just opened