# Error producing citations from an Rmd with citations using RefManageR

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I am trying to format citations in a PDF report using `RefManageR`. The following `test.Rmd` code produces different results depending how I process it:

````
---
title: "Test bib"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: biblatex
--- 

# References

```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(RefManageR)
BibOptions(cite.style = "authoryear", bib.style = "authoryear", no.print.fields = c("url"), check.entries = FALSE, style = "markdown")
zbib <- ReadZotero(group = "130380", 
                   .params = list(collection = "MYKE5653"))
```

# Citations

This is an example of a citation in the text `r Cite(zbib, "warner_development_2016")`.   
`r Cite(zbib, "tang_development_2016")` an other citation.

# References
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
PrintBibliography(zbib)
```
````

0) Just to have a reference, using the 'knit' button in Rstudio (see '1)'), I get an html page with the expected two references (but I could not find a way to use max.names = 1 to limit citations length!!).

1) As pointed out in this question I am ['missing options on knit button'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694198/rstudio-knit-button-is-not-showing-options-continued). From the Console   `knit2pdf("test.Rmd")`  aborts with the following messages:

> output file: TestBib_v2.md
>   Error in tinytex::latexmk(basename(out), engine = compiler, ...) :
>     The input file 'TestBib_v2.md' does not have the .tex extension

2) With the command   `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")`  I get a nice PDF where citations are limited to one author BUT, all references in the .bib are listed not only the two cited ones!!

Is there something evident I am missing (like a general guide with minimal explanations on the possible ways to produce a PDF from an Rmd with citations and bibliography - I installed and tried to understand https://yihui.name/tinytex/ ) or is the use of LaTex related processes just inherently complicated and unstable?

PS - I found these pages helpful:
* [the-tex-family-tree-latex-pdftex-xelatex-luatex-context](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2012/12/01/the-tex-family-tree-latex-pdftex-xelatex-luatex-context.html)
* [bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html might help?

Comment: Using Rmarkdown bibliograpy: option doesn't allow the direct connection to Zotero.
I tried changing the 'engine' and the 'citation_package' respectively to 'xelatex' and 'biblatex'. I had some improvement on other aspects though the list of references is not yet limited to the citations I used.

Comment: Have you read the vignettes of the RefManageR package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RefManageR/

Comment: Yes, I started from there. The manual states that  `PrintBibliography()`  will " _...only print the references that have been cited..._ ". The list of references produced using the 'knit' button (I have only the html option) is correct but the request for a `pdf_document` is ignored. To produce the .pdf I specified in the YAML header, I have to use   `rmarkdown::render()` and the list is no longer limited to cited refs.

Comment: You could use `NoCite` as a workaround.  Just place `r NoCite(myBib, c("warner_development_2016")`, "tang_development_2016")` before the `PrintBibliography` command.

Comment: I also have problems with `max.names`, it doesn't work at all. On the other hand the author-year output produces quite peculiar references, not what it should be according to the manual (output xaringan).